# Removing leading 0 from third column

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'm trying to remove the first 0 from the third column in my CSV file

tel.csv -

```
 test,01test,01234567890
 test,01test,09876054321
```

I have been trying to use the following with no luck -

```
cat tel.csv | sed 's/^0*//'
```

Comment: please update the question to show the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),0\(.*\)$/\1,\2,\3/' file.csv
```

---

Or `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(/^0/, "", $3)}1' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- 3rd column consists of only numbers (`0-9`)
- 3rd column could have multiple leading `0's`

Adding a row with a 3rd column that has multiple leading `0's`:

```
$ cat tel.csv
test,01test,01234567890
test,01test,09876054321
test,02test,00001234567890
```

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$3=$3+0}1' tel.csv
test,01test,1234567890
test,01test,9876054321
test,02test,1234567890
```

Where: adding `0` to a number (`$3+0`) has the side effect of removing leading `0's`.

Answer (score 0):

If the third field is the last field, as it is in the sample lines:

```
sed 's/,0\([^,]*\)$/,\1/' file
```